# Using JavaScript in Flutter

Tags: javascript, flutter, puppeteer

I Am creating a bot that can access websites and I am creating a GUI for it using flutter. I want to write the code for the bot accessing the website in javascript but I am struggling to find anything that can allow me to execute a script on the click of a button. I have attempted to use flutter_js but when I press the button to call the script, I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: expecting '('
    at <eval>:1

JSError (SyntaxError: expecting '('
    at <eval>:1
)
```

The code for the flutter to Js is:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_js/flutter_js.dart';
import 'package:flutter_js/quickjs/qjs_typedefs.dart';

void addFromJs(JavascriptRuntime _javascriptRuntime)
  async{
    String test_code = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/bot_code/testcode.js");
    final eval = _javascriptRuntime.evaluate(test_code+ """openTrapstar()""");
    final res = eval.stringResult;
  }
```

And the code for the js script is:

```
import * as puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

function openTrapstar(){

    (async () => {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto('https://uk.trapstarlondon.com/');
        console.log("HERE");
        await browser.close();
    })();

};
 openTrapstar();
```

addFromJs is then called in an OnPressed function where the button is.

From this post I want to know what I am doing wrong in flutter_js or if it's even possible to run a script like this in flutter_js.

If not how can I go about achieving this goal.